# How to release heap memory of thread local storage

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread, thread-local, thread-local-storage

I have a structure used for thread local storage like this:

```
namespace {
 typedef boost::unordered_map< std::string, std::vector<xxx> > YYY;
 boost::thread_specific_ptr<YYY> cache;

 void initCache() {
     //The first time called by the current thread.
     if (!cache.get()){
         cache.reset(new YYY());
     }
 }

void clearCache() {
     if (cache.get()){
         cache.reset();
     }
}
}
```

And a class whose object could have been created by the `main thread`:

```
class A {
public:
    void f() {
        initCache();
        //and for example:
        insertIntoCache();
    }
    ~A(){
        clearCache();// <-- Does/Can this do anything good ??
    }
}
```

Multiple threads can access object(s) of `A` stored, for example, in a global container. Each of these threads need to call `A::f()` from time to time. So they create their own copy of `cache` on the `heap` once , and finally join when they done with all their jobs.

So the question is : who is going to clean-up threads' memory? and How?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to call `clearCache()`.

Once the thread exits or the `thread_specific_ptr` goes out of scope, the cleanup function will be invoked. If you don't pass a cleanup function to the `thread_specific_ptr`'s constructor, it will just use `delete`.

Comment: I see, can you please give a a reference for more reading. thanks

Comment: Read the documentation for `thread_specific_ptr` at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html#thread.thread_local_storage.thread_specific_ptr